# Get index name from alias in elasticsearch using php client library

Tags: php, search, elasticsearch

I am creating index with alias and I want to get index name from alias  in `elasticsearch` using `php` client library. Below is my code to add alias in index.

```
$params['body'] = array(
        'actions' => array(
            array(
                'add' => array(
                    'index' => 'solatiers_with_alias',
                    'alias' => 'solatiers_alias'
                    )
                )
            )
        );
$client->indices()->updateAliases($params);
```

How can I retrieve index name from alias?

Answer (score 0):

You can get retrieve index name by

```
function myfunction($value,$key)
{
 if($key="index"){
    echo $value;
    break;
    }
}
array_walk_recursive($params['body'],"myfunction");
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like this:

```
echo $params['body']['actions'][0]['add']['index'];
```

There are other ways to write this with different syntax like $params->body->actions etc but mixing associative keys with numerical ones is a PITA in this case.